# hyperref doesn't work properly in memoir for bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, memoir

When I use hyperref in memoir and click the link of bibliography in the table of contents, I jump to the line *just below* Bibliography. (This behavior is different from when I click the other chapters in the table of contents.) How can I adjust? Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter
\chapter{Main Body}
We all are on the sholders of giants~\cite{T}.

\backmatter
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{T} S.~Tand, On the sholders of giants, (2017).
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really build the `thebibliography` environment by hand?

Comment: @Mico Well, I do. But I don't have to (if it helps) and also understand this is not a modern nor smart solution. (I prefer this solution to avoid digging into TeXnical problems to adjust style for each journal.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`memoir` is inserting an unnessary \phantomsection which moves the link destination down. Imho this is a bug that should be reported. A work around is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@memb@bchap{\phantomsection}{}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter
\chapter{Main Body}
We all are on the sholders of giants~\cite{T}.

\backmatter
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{T} S.~Tand, On the sholders of giants, (2017).
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works for me (except misspelling s/meakatother/makeatother; I cannot edit only those because of characters limit). If it a bug should be reported, where should I report to?

Comment: I corrected the typo. Regarding the bug: write the maintainer of memoir @daleif.